# Problem with Docker(sudo: status: command not found)

Tags: docker, terminal, sudo, ubuntu-20.04, status

I have a problem. I want to check docker status but there is an error which [sudo: status: command not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qf9zq.png). Btw I have install the [docker and sudo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kAeDO.png).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Instead use sudo you can manage docker as a non-root user.

You need read this: [Post-installation steps for Linux](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/)

Comment: Thanks for the guide. it is working now